# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string error

Tags: c++, macos

When I run my code at first there is no error.
After I type `Test string` then `I a a` it gives me:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string`

I don't know if it is about the string functions or my input.

*p.s. This program is to delete, insert, and replace letters in a string*

My code is below

```
using namespace std;

string str;
bool flag = true;

void del(char p)
{
    int pos = str.find(p);
    if (pos != string::npos)
    {
        str.erase(pos,1);
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "N" << endl;
        flag = false;
    }
}

void ins(string p1, string p2)
{
    int pos = str.find(p1[0]);
    if (pos == string::npos)
    {
        cout << "N" << endl;
        flag = false;
        return ;
    }
    int newpos = pos;
    while (pos != string::npos)
    {
        pos = str.find(p1,newpos);
        newpos = pos + 1;
    }
    str.insert(pos,p2);
    return ;
}

void repl(string p1, string p2)
{
    int pos = 0;
    int find = 0;
    find = str.find(p1[0],pos);
    if (find == string::npos)
    {
        cout << "N" << endl;
        flag = false;
        return ;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        find = str.find(p1[0],pos);
        if (find != string::npos)
        {
            str[find] = p2[0];
            pos = find + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return ;
}

int main()
{
    getline(cin,str);
    char a;
    cin >> a;
    //cout << a << endl;
    if (a == 'D')
    {
        char p1;
        cin >> p1;
        del(p1);
    }
    else if (a == 'I')
    {
        string p1,p2;
        cin >> p1 >> p2;
        ins(p1,p2);
    }
    else if (a == 'R')
    {
        string p1,p2;
        cin >> p1 >> p2;
        repl(p1,p2);
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using VS Code on Mac. I don't know if it would help.
*I don't know what I can type, but it tells me my post is mostly code and I need to add more details......*

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger. Use it to catch the exception when it's being thrown, and find out where in your code it happens. Then examine all involved variables to see their values and make sure all of them are valid. I'll bet that `newpos` will be out of range (which it could be while still being not equal to [`string::npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos)).

Comment: Hi, what is the purpose of this code? Homework? Because you are reimplementing existing STL library functions.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.